# Changing color of TextView

Tags: java, android

I want to change the color of a `TextView` inside my `Activity`s `ListView` by java code. `ListView` contains multiple rows which are fed by a `MatrixCursor` and an `ArrayAdapter`. The color of the `TextView` should be green or white which should be determined by an `if` clause. How can I accomplish this?

```
    citem = NameManager.getciList();
    NameManager.WriteName(citem);
    MatrixCursor cursor;
    cursor = NameManager.getnameList();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    if (cursor.getString(9).equals("yes")){
        //TODO set color of R.id.name color here
    }
    String[] from = { "name", "info", "status", "path", "folder", BaseColumns._ID };
    int[] to = { R.id.name, R.id.info, R.id.status, R.id.path };
    final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write your own custom adapter, where you can set color, size of list items.see this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950025/custom-listview-adapter-android) it will let u know an idea.
below is lis with blue text color

[image: r]