# how to create custom adapter with listview and use it within jsoup onpostexecute

Tags: android, listview, jsoup, android-arrayadapter

I am using jsoup to scrape html from a web page. But I am unable to get data into two text views in my listview. I am using ArrayAdapter and i can set text to one text view.

how can i create a custom adapter to get text in two textview with jsoup?

Answer (score 2):

You can [Google](https://www.google.com.tr/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=android+listview+custom+adapter&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=-ASIVL2LBsX-ygOL_oHwDQ#pws=0&q=android+listview+custom+adapter)  it
or
You can search in Stackoverflow

1- [custom-adapter-for-list-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

2- [custom-listview-adapter-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950025/custom-listview-adapter-android)